# add st nd rd th to date in batch

Tags: date, batch-file, suffix

I would like to add a suffix to the date's in a batch program.

> This is what I belive would work (if done proper) and is also what I need help with!

`if %date:~0,-8%==01 set "newdateday1=1st"
if %date:~0,-8%==02 set "newdateday2=2nd"
if %date:~0,-8%==03 set "newdateday3=3rd"
if %date:~0,-8% gtr 4 set "newdateday4plus=th"`

So just to sum up what I need is an output like this

> 21st of August 2017

instead of this

> 21-08-2017

as the first looks way better in my opinion :)

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. [Edit] your question to contain relevant code as a [mcve]

Comment: I'm sure you could do such a thing using a simple `If` command. After all the only numbers which need anything different from `th` are those ending with `1`, `2` & `3` as you have shown above. If you were to have your date components in variables `%variable:~-1%` would resolve to that last integer; so three lines in the form `If "%variable:~-1%"=="2" Set "suffix=nd"` should be all you need.

Comment: How is this unclear? "But now I would also like to add the suffix for dates. So for example

1st
2nd
3rd
4th"

Comment: You need to remember that in the majority of cases `0` would require `th` too. I see no reason to change the code from detecting only the last integer. Start by `Set "suffix=th"` then three lines as I've already provided, `If "%variable:~-1%"=="1" Set "suffix=st"`, `If "%variable:~-1%"=="2" Set "suffix=nd"` & `If "%variable:~-1%"=="3" Set "suffix=rd"`.

Comment: This is what I have done `set "suffix=th"`
`If "%date:~-1%"=="1" Set "suffix=st"`
`If "%date:~-1%"=="2" Set "suffix=nd"`
`If "%date:~-1%"=="3" Set "suffix=rd"`

`echo date ^= %date%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use something like this:

```bat
@Echo Off

Rem Echo This script is based upon a default date format ending dd/MM/yyyy
Rem Echo Where "/" can be any usual separator and leading 0s are included.

Set "ToD=%DATE%"
Set "DoM=%ToD:~-10,2%"
Set "MoY=%ToD:~-7,2%"
Set "Yr=%ToD:~-4%"

If Not "%DoM:~,1%"=="1" (
    If "%DoM:~-1%"=="1" Set "DaS=%DoM%st"
    If "%DoM:~-1%"=="2" Set "DaS=%DoM%nd"
    If "%DoM:~-1%"=="3" Set "DaS=%DoM%rd")
If Not Defined DaS Set "DaS=%DoM%th"
If "%DaS:~,1%"=="0" Set "DaS=%DaS:~1%"

If Not "%MoY:~,1%"=="1" (
    If "%MoY:~-1%"=="1" Set "MaS=%MoY%st"
    If "%MoY:~-1%"=="2" Set "MaS=%MoY%nd"
    If "%MoY:~-1%"=="3" Set "MaS=%MoY%rd")
If Not Defined MaS Set "MaS=%MoY%th"
If "%MaS:~,1%"=="0" Set "MaS=%MaS:~1%"

If Not "%Yr:~-2,1%"=="1" (
    If "%Yr:~-1%"=="1" Set "YaS=%Yr%st"
    If "%Yr:~-1%"=="2" Set "YaS=%Yr%nd"
    If "%Yr:~-1%"=="3" Set "YaS=%Yr%rd")
If Not Defined YaS Set "YaS=%Yr%th"

Echo Today is the %DaS% day of the %MaS% month of the %YaS% year

Timeout -1
```

Comment: What does that last line do? `IF "%DOM:~,1%"=="0" Set "DOM=%DOM:~1%"`

Comment: Anyways I have made it work with the days.. now for the months and for the year I have tried to do this 
`if "%date:~2,-5%"=="01" set "month=January"`

all the way from the 1st month to the 12th month

`if "%date:~2,-5%"=="12" set "month=December"`


But it outputs this "21st of  2017" so it lacks the month.

And for the year I have just done `set year=2017` but is there a way to check the year? ( This is medium priority)

Comment: That line removes a leading zero so `07th` would read `7th`. If you wish to expand your code that far from the initial question, I'd suggest you create a new question as this one was fully answered.

Comment: It was never fully answered I showed in the beginning what I was needing help with, but I will create a new question...

Comment: I have added the code to my answer relevant to appending suffixes also to the months and years. There are many examples on this site of methods to translate/output the name of the month, which is outside of the original scope of this question.